# DiscreteConvolution

Tags: convolution

I am not an expert in discrete Convolutions so perhaps there is a mathematical misunderstanding with me and or the options. But shouldn't convolve average over the two lists like in the continuous case? My result is not symmetrical (I tried other options instead of 1 too).

Starting from this I extended my question to an example with continuous functions f,g,h and their discretisation

```
AA = {0., 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.}
BB = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
ListConvolve[AA, BB, 1]
{%} // MatrixPlot
```

Thanks everyone for helping clearing out my confusion
PS: I also need it for two (nnxmm)-matrices but already have the problem in 1D

EDIT: Dear all, thanks for the feedback to my question. I cannot precisely answer what my expected outpit is as I was asked, except I expected it to be symmetric

In the continuous case the Convolution of two 'similar' functions result in a symmetric result (also when checking the very long explicit result mathematica gives back)

```
f[x_] := If[-1 <= x <= 1, 1 - RealAbs[x], 0]
g[x_] := 
 If[-1 <= x <= 0, 1 - 2 RealAbs[x + 0.5], 0] + 
  If[0 <= x <= 1, 1 - 2 RealAbs[x - 0.5], 0]
h[x_] :=Convolve[f[y], g[y], y, x];
Plot[{h[x], f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1.1, 1.1}]
```

However in the discrete case, also for f and g as just posted, my result is non symmetrical. Is this a problem with even and odd length of the arrays? Because when I was playing around, it is not.

```
AA = Table[f[n], {n, -1, 1, 0.1}];
BB = Table[g[n], {n, -1, 1, 0.1}];
CC = 0.1 ListConvolve[AA, BB, (Length@AA + 1)/2, 0]
DD = Table[h[n], {n, -1, 1, 0.1}];
ListPlot[{AA, BB, CC, DD}, Joined -> True]
```

EDIT2: Thanks to all the help so far. I understand the problem better now (but not yet completely). I am again working out my continuous problem with f, g and h. I understand why I need the 0 as explained by @Mauricio , I understand why I need the midpoint (Length@AA+1)/2 as explained by Lucas, I don't understand why I need a value 0.1 in CC (as seen by me by eye) to make CC and DD, the discretization of the continuous case, look fitting.

Comment: `ListConvolve[AA, BB, 5]`?

Comment: If you provide an expected output, it would be easier to provide guidance. I'm not quite sure what you're expecting.

Comment: If you want an averaging effect, you need to chose the kernel corrctly. For instance: AA = {0., 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.}; BB = {1/3, 1/3, 1/3};
ListConvolve[BB, AA] averages every three of the terms in AA together.

Comment: Dear @LukasLang , thanks! what is the 5 doing?

Comment: Dear @lericr , I am also not quite sure except it's being symmetric. I elaborated on my expectations in my posting

Comment: Dear @bills thanks, I don't want a smoothing (or a sharpening or all the other possibilities) via a fitting kernel. I want a result that expresses how the shape of one is modified by the other and I am wondering why my result is non-symmetric

Comment: The answer as to why it's not symmetric is easy. You used a third argument of 1. The documentation explains how the third argument is used. You can choose an argument that will give you symmetry, e.g. `{1,-1}`.

Answer (score 3):

The `ListConvolve` specifications are a bit tricky to wrap your head around, but they are extremely flexible once you did: As noted in the documentation, the third argument of `ListConvolve` specifies the alignment of the two lists for the first and last term of the summation. Some examples (note that by default, `BB` will be cyclically extended if there are overhangs, and remember that the kernel will be reversed):

- The default, `{-1,1}`: This means that the element `AA[[1]]` is aligned with the first element of `BB`, and `AA[[-1]]` with the last:

  [image]
- "Maximal overhang", `{1,-1}`: The element `AA[[-1]]` will be aligned with the first element of `BB`, and `AA[[1]]` with the last:

  [image]
- Right overhang, `-1` or `{-1,-1}`:

  [image]
- Left overhang, `1` or `{1,1}`:

  [image]
- Symmetric overhang, `5` or `{5,5}` (or, more generally, `(Length@AA+1)/2`):

  [image]

Comment: Thanks alot! I extended my question with your comment on sysmmetric overhang and my continuous examples

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, what you want here is:

```
ListConvolve[AA, BB, {1, -1}, 0]
```

Here the "continuous-time" behavior is done by padding with zeros. But be careful with the meaning of zeros before the first non-zero entry. For example,

```
AA = {0., 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.}
BB = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
ListConvolve[AA, BB, {1, -1}, 0]
```

and

```
AA = {0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3}
BB = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
ListConvolve[AA, BB, {1, -1}, 0]
```

will return the same set of non-zero entries but the first version will have additional zeros.

Comment: Dear Mauricio, thanks alot! I understand the padding with zero-part. 
Since the result has different length, it is still a problem and e.g. no solution for my posed AA,BB,CC-problem or do I missunderstand something (again)?
And sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that ListConvolve's options are confusing. So are the options under ListCorrelate, which is basically the same function, but with the meaning of the arguments scrambled. Below are three different ways to convolve (filter) data x with a kernel h: convolution. correlation, and using a frequency domain method. The only difference (other than numerical factors) is in the way edge conditions are handled with padding.

```
h = {0., 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.};
x = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
n = Length[x] + Length[h] - 1;
xPad = PadRight[x, n];
```

In the convolution method, the kernel h is thought of as the impulse response of a linear time-invariant system and the x is thought of as the input to that system. The convolution yConv is then the output of the system.

```
yConv = ListConvolve[h, x, {1, 1}, 0];
yConvPad = ListConvolve[h, xPad, {1, 1}]

{0., 0., 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0., 0.}
```

You can see the nice symmetry that the OP is looking for. In the correlation method, the kernel h is thought of as a marker or mask and x is thought of as the data that is to be examined. The correlation yCorr is then how much like x the kernel is at each place in the sequence.

```
yCorr = ListCorrelate[Reverse[h], x, {-1, -1}, 0];
yCorrPad = ListCorrelate[Reverse[h], xPad, {-1, -1}]

{0., 0., 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0., 0.}
```

The Fourier method exploits the fact from Fourier Transforms that the product of the transforms is equal to the convolution of the time domain signals. The following calculate the Fourier transform of h (ffth) and the Fourier transform of x (fftx), after padding to the same length. The element-by-element product is then inverse transformed, giving yFourier. which is numerically the same as the above methods.

```
ffth = Fourier[PadRight[h, n], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
fftx =  Fourier[PadRight[x, n], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
yFourier = InverseFourier[ffth fftx, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]

{-9.79609*10^-17, 7.75523*10^-17, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, -2.61229*10^-17, -7.75523*10^-17}
```

Note that you'll want to Chop off the (numerically) zero entries.

```
Chop[yFourier]
{0., 0., 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0., 0.}
```

Sometimes you also end up with (essentially) zero complex terms, so beware of that, too.